# How to identify multiply defined and unresolved references?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

When compiling my `.tex` file, latexmk responds with

```
  Latexmk: Summary of warnings: Latex failed to resolve 2 reference(s) Latex found 1 multiply defined reference(s)
```

1. What excatly does it mean when there are *unresolved* references?
2. Is there an easy way of identifying multiply defined references? (I have a 3000 line .bib file)

Comment: reference are not from the bib, but from \label/\ref commands. The log-file will show you which are undefined and which have been set more then once.

Comment: Use `JabRef` for organizing the references of a database specified in (.bib) format. I guess this will suffice your need by excluding the duplicates.

Comment: My .log file is 5000 lines long :). Can you be more specific on how to pinpoint the reference of interest? Thanks for suggesting `JabRef`, I will look into it.

Comment: What text editor do you use ? How do you compile your `.tex` file ?
Some softwares are more specific about this kind of message (ex: TeXStudio).

Comment: Package `refcheck` can be of use here

Comment: I use TeXStudio and Latexmk. The answer of JPi helped me find my multiply defined reference.

Comment: `refcheck` does not seem to work properly when using `\autoref{label}`.

Comment: I didn't know about `refcheck` and tried it, but it resulted in all sorts of weird errors, including missing $.  There appears to be a conflict, possibly with cleveref or hyperref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A reference that has not been found, e.g. you've used `\ref{ex}` without a matching `\label{ex}` *or* with a matching `\label{ex}` that has not been found yet.  Another run of LaTeX should resolve the latter.
2. Look in the log file for the words `multiply` and `undefined`.

Comment: Searching the `.log` for "undefined" did it for me!